# What is the exact difference and advantages/disadvantages of initializeUnorderedBulkOperation and initializeOrderedBulkOperation?

Tags: java, mongodb, bulkinsert

I am working on a functionality in java where I have to do a `BulkWriteOperation` using mongoDb. Here I came across the two types of BulkWriteOperation:

- `initializeUnorderedBulkOperation()`
- `initializeOrderedBulkOperation()`

I have reffered [this](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.13/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#initializeUnorderedBulkOperation--) for both the above. 
What is the exact difference in terms of performance, and which should be preferred?

I also want to log duplicate records in exception so that the log file will contain the duplicates and can do analysis on it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the "exact" difference is in the naming of the methods in that one is "Orderred" and the other is "Un-Orderred". But there is a little more to it than just that.

- **Orderred**: Of course executes the statements in the batch in the same order they are created in. If any statement fails then the batch execution will halt at that point ( not a rollback ) and return an error in the WriteResult.
- **Un-Orderred**: Does not preseve the order of creation in the batch for execution and can process in any order and in parallel. If any occurs, rather than returning an exception result in the WriteResponse the errors are simply reported as a list within the Write response

So ["Orderred"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp) will be in order and fail out at any error, whereas ["UnOrderred"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp) will submit all batched operations but just report the errors in the response.

UnOrderred can possibly return faster due to not relying on sequential execution. But if you need the batched actions to execute in a certain order the Orderred is the correct approach.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. Then in my case I should prefer Un-Orderred?

Comment: @Nakul91 What is your case? ( I don't read external links, it should be in your question ). The differences are spelled out, it depends on which one you need 1. The batch executed in a specific order, 2. Prepared to process in any order and deal with error handling on inspection.

Comment: Considering the answer I do not want to halt my execution in between if some exceptions occurred. I do not want any particular order also need inspection. So case 2 is for me.